# How to slice the list column by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[4,84,68]]},index=[0,1,0])
```

What I want to get :

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2],[3,5],[4,84]] },index=[0,1,0])
Out[690]: 
         A
0   [1, 2]
1   [3, 5]
0  [4, 84]
```

The approach as of now :

```
[r[i:i+2] for i, r in zip(df.index, df.A)]

Out[695]: [[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 84]]
```

However, when I try to using `apply` `lambda`, I feel lost .....and Can not get the expected out put

So far I have tried:

```
df[['A']].apply(lambda x : x[(x.index):(x.index+2)])
```

Can you help me out , Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = np.array(df.A.values.tolist())
i = np.arange(len(df))[:, None]
j = np.arange(2) + df.index.values[:, None]

pd.DataFrame(dict(A=a[i, j].tolist()), df.index)

         A
0   [1, 2]
1   [3, 5]
0  [4, 84]
```

Comment: [1, 3] this one should be [3,5] :)

Comment: Took me long enough (-:

Comment: This make a lot of sense

Comment: Your way is still quicker... at least over this data.

Comment: T_T Still did not what i am doing wrong by using `x.index` with `lambda`

Comment: `df[['A']].apply(lambda x : x.A[(x.name):(x.name+2)], 1)`